# My top bar isn't changing colors on hover

Tags: html, css

I am *trying* to make my own website, but I'm having some difficulty with my top bar not changing color on hovor. If you think you can help, please answer.

`index.html` is working perfectly, just thought it might need to be added.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> my site </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="gradecalc/gradecalc.html" >Grade Calculator</a>
        <li> <a href="aboutme/aboutme.html" >About Me</a></li>
        <li> <a href="resume/resume.html" >Résumé</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

`index.css`, stuff only for the header.

```
header ul { /*selects list of stuff*/
  list-style-type: none; /*no bullet points*/
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #70deef;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
header li { /*selects list element*/
  float: left; /*move to left*/
}
header li a { 
  display: block; /*makes a rectangle*/
  color: #ffffff; /*white*/
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
}
header li a.active { /*when hovering??*/
  background-color: #d6d6d6; /*grey*/

}
```

I thought `header li a.active` would change the color on hover. Why isn't it doing so?

Comment: Applying a class like `.active` on hover only works in conjunction with JavaScript. There are already multiple answers how you do it with a pseudo class in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `a:hover`. Not `a.active` or something like this.

For more informations, see [CSS :hover Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp), [CSS Pseudo-classes](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) or more generally [CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

```css
header ul {
  /*selects list of stuff*/
  list-style-type: none;
  /*no bullet points*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #70deef;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
header li {
  /*selects list element*/
  float: left;
  /*move to left*/
}
header li a {
  display: block;
  /*makes a rectangle*/
  color: #ffffff;
  /*white*/
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
}
header li a:hover {
  /*when hovering??*/
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
  /*grey*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>my site</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="gradecalc/gradecalc.html">Grade Calculator</a>
        <li> <a href="aboutme/aboutme.html">About Me</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="resume/resume.html">Résumé</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why does the bar get bigger in grey?

Comment: Because your `a`-element have a `padding: 20px` which have no color. If you add color to your `a`-element, you can see the padding. You could prevent this by changing the padding from `header li a` to `padding: 20px 20px 10px;`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the css selector `:hover`

```
 header li a:hover { /*when hovering??*/
  background-color: #d6d6d6; /*grey*/
}
```